# Trying to update parent view frame according to UILabel's text size

Tags: swift, autolayout, uilabel

I have a view and inside it I have a UILabel. I want the view to change its width according to the length of the text.
What I tried is to first perform `SizeToFit()` on my UILabel, hoping this will change its frame, and then put the labels frame into the view's frame.
This doesn't work, I guess because of auto layout restrictions. 
This is the code of what I tried:

```
private func example(){
    self.labelInsideView.sizeToFit()
    viewThatContainsLabel.frame = labelInsideView.frame
    self.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

It seems pretty obvious that this won't work, because I am pretty sure size to fit does not change the frame. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make an `IBOutlet` of your `UIView's` width constraint and then simply change the width constraint constant to the width of `UILabel`

```
self.labelInsideView.sizeToFit()
self.widthConstraintOfView.constant = labelInsideView.frame.size.width
self.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Comment: Awesome idea. Will try it out

Answer (score 0):

Why are you even using this function. Your view should have constraints.

Leading = Top = Bottom = 8 and Trailing >= 20

Your label should have all the constraints equal to 5.

Now try and add any text in your Label and you'll get updated frame of the view without using this function. Just try this once.

Comment: I will look into this as well. Sounds interesting. Though your answer involves magic numbers and I use relative constraints for this so I will need to translate it somehow.

Comment: These numbers are just for example. Once you see appropriate results modify them according to your needs.